# nginx serving www subdomain with default page

Tags: nginx, web, default

I'm running ubuntu server 18.04 and have just installed nginx. I'm struggling with a wired issue that when calling http://example.com nginx serves it with the default page from /var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html (I've modified the file to be sure :-), just added another line 'Is this really me?' to it).

[serving from /var/www/html/*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXCar.png)

But when calling http://www.example.com (adding the www subdomain), nginx responds with what seems to be the real default page, but I have no idea where it is coming from.

[serving the "unkown" default page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1AN9.png)

I found that there's another index.html available in /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html using find / -name *.html which is looks like the default page, too, so I modified this page as well to be sure nginx does not use this file to serve http://www.example.com:

[modified /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOwMj.png)

But still (I've refreshed my cache several times :-) it gives me this default page without any modifications I made to the two files mentioned before.

I already checked my DNS entries @ and www that both point to the same IP. Also I've not done any major changes to the nginx.conf or default file:

nginx.conf

```
 user www-data;
 worker_processes auto;
 pid /run/nginx.pid;
 include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

default

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #       deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}
```

Can you guys enlighten me what's fundamentally wrong here?!

Comment: I'd have guessed it's the `server_name` line, but you only have the one, and no virtual hosts?

Comment: Yeah, it’s only this line and only default file is available in sites-enabled. Another finding I had when trying to redirect all requests from http to https was that it worked for all requests except the www one. http:// example.com got redirected to https:// example.com, and calling https:// example.com or https:// www.example.com worked as expected. Only for http:// www.example.com it was giving me this default page again, and no redirect.

Comment: ok, seems like chrome is giving me some trouble. It works when using IE or mobile, so no nginx issue >.> When using chrome via my laptop, it's acting weird as described above.

Comment: Huh, that seems wrong. Best guess Chrome has cached a copy of the site before you configured it completely? Maybe hard refresh ctrl+shift+R, or there might be something obvious in the debugging tools network view?

Comment: Yeah, good thing is its not about nginx :-) Also it seems to be specific to one of the two of my laptops only. The other one works fine, as well as mobile. On the one not showing the proper page I tried CTRL+F5 already. Also clearing all browser data except passwords on the advanced tab fails.